# Extremely long error message when gulp closure compiler crashes

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, gulp, google-closure-compiler

I'm working on a web-app, for which I use the google closure compiler with gulp. Here is my gulp-script:

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const closureCompiler = require('google-closure-compiler').gulp();
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

const sourceFiles = [
  './src/**.js',
  './src/**/*.js',
  '!./src/**.test.js',
  '!./src/**/*.test.js'
];

gulp.task('minify', (done) => {
  gulp
    .src(sourceFiles)
    .pipe(
      closureCompiler({
        compilation_level: 'ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS',
        warning_level: 'VERBOSE',
        js_output_file: 'gameshow.min.js',
        dependency_mode: 'PRUNE',
        entry_point: './gameshow',
        formatting: 'PRETTY_PRINT'
      })
    )
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('/'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
  done();
});
```

Whenever i have an error in my code (e.g. wrong import path) the closure compiler seems to crash after it prints the warnings and error messages. But then I get this:

```
[10:07:58] Using gulpfile C:\WorkSpace\gameshow\gulpfile.js
[10:07:58] Starting 'minify'...
[10:07:58] Finished 'minify' after 16 ms     
gulp-google-closure-compiler: message/mainmessagemanager.js:40:5: WARNING - [JSC_BAD_JSDOC_ANNOTATION] Parse error. illegal use of unknown JSDoc tag "listens"; ignoring it. Place another character before the @ to stop JSCompiler from parsing it as an annotation.
  40|    * @listens ViewManager#new-view
           ^

message/messagemanager.js:20:5: WARNING - [JSC_BAD_JSDOC_ANNOTATION] Parse error. illegal use 
of unknown JSDoc tag "listens"; ignoring it. Place another character before the @ to stop JSCompiler from parsing it as an annotation.
  20|    * @listens Observable#observable-update
           ^

data/team.js:39:59: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable Game is undeclared
  39|     this.teamName = new Observable(`team.${id}.team name`, Game.TeamsOrPlayers.getValue() ? `Team ${id}` : `Player ${id}`);
                                                                 ^^^^

1 error(s), 2 warning(s)

node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

CustomError: Error in gulp-google-closure-compiler
    at C:\WorkSpace\gameshow\node_modules\google-closure-compiler\lib\gulp\index.js:211:28    
Error: gulp-google-closure-compiler: Compilation errors occurred
    at CompilationStream._compilationComplete (C:\WorkSpace\gameshow\node_modules\google-closure-compiler\lib\gulp\index.js:238:28)
    at C:\WorkSpace\gameshow\node_modules\google-closure-compiler\lib\gulp\index.js:208:14    
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Emitted 'error' event on Domain instance at:
    at CompilationStream.emit (node:domain:540:12)
    at C:\WorkSpace\gameshow\node_modules\google-closure-compiler\lib\gulp\index.js:211:14    
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  original: CustomError: gulp-google-closure-compiler: Compilation errors occurred
      at CompilationStream._compilationComplete (C:\WorkSpace\gameshow\node_modules\google-closure-compiler\lib\gulp\index.js:238:28)
      at C:\WorkSpace\gameshow\node_modules\google-closure-compiler\lib\gulp\index.js:208:14  
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    domainEmitter: CompilationStream {
      _readableState: ReadableState {
        objectMode: true,
        highWaterMark: 16,
        buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
        length: 0,
        pipes: [
          DestroyableTransform {
            _readableState: [ReadableState],
            readable: true,
            _events: [Object: null prototype],
            _eventsCount: 7,
            _maxListeners: undefined,
            _writableState: [WritableState],
            writable: true,
            allowHalfOpen: true,
            _transformState: [Object],
            _destroyed: false,
            _transform: [Function: sourceMapWrite],
            [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
          }
        ],
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        constructed: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        emitClose: true,
        autoDestroy: true,
        destroyed: false,
        errored: null,
        closed: false,
        closeEmitted: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrainWriters: null,
        multiAwaitDrain: false,
        readingMore: false,
        dataEmitted: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null,
        [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
      },
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {
        prefinish: [Function: prefinish],
        end: [Function: bound onceWrapper] { listener: [Function: onend] },
        data: [Function: ondata]
      },
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: WritableState {
        objectMode: true,
        highWaterMark: 16,
        finalCalled: true,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: true,
        ended: true,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        afterWriteTickInfo: null,
        buffered: [],
        bufferedIndex: 0,
        allBuffers: true,
        allNoop: true,
        pendingcb: 1,
        constructed: true,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        emitClose: true,
        autoDestroy: true,
        errored: null,
        closed: false,
        closeEmitted: false,
        [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
      },
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      compilationOptions_: {
        compilation_level: 'ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS',
        warning_level: 'VERBOSE',
        js_output_file: 'gameshow.min.js',
        dependency_mode: 'PRUNE',
        entry_point: './gameshow',
        formatting: 'PRETTY_PRINT'
      },
      streamMode_: 'BOTH',
      logger_: Object [console] {
        log: [Function: log],
        warn: [Function: warn],
        dir: [Function: dir],
        time: [Function: time],
        timeEnd: [Function: timeEnd],
        timeLog: [Function: timeLog],
        trace: [Function: trace],
        assert: [Function: assert],
        clear: [Function: clear],
        count: [Function: count],
        countReset: [Function: countReset],
        group: [Function: group],
        groupEnd: [Function: groupEnd],
        table: [Function: table],
        debug: [Function: debug],
        info: [Function: info],
        dirxml: [Function: dirxml],
        error: [Function: error],
        groupCollapsed: [Function: groupCollapsed],
        Console: [Function: Console],
        profile: [Function: profile],
        profileEnd: [Function: profileEnd],
        timeStamp: [Function: timeStamp],
        context: [Function: context],
        createTask: [Function: createTask]
      },
      PLUGIN_NAME_: 'gulp-google-closure-compiler',
      fileList_: [
        File {
          stat: Stats {
            dev: 1946988696,
            mode: 33206,
            nlink: 1,
            uid: 0,
            gid: 0,
            rdev: 0,
            blksize: 4096,
            ino: 8725724278860352,
            size: 527,
            blocks: 8,
            atimeMs: 1686297160464.599,
            mtimeMs: 1686076160031.9421,
            ctimeMs: 1686076160031.9421,
            birthtimeMs: 1680796196520.1814,
            atime: 2023-06-09T07:52:40.465Z,
            mtime: 2023-06-06T18:29:20.032Z,
            ctime: 2023-06-06T18:29:20.032Z,
            birthtime: 2023-04-06T15:49:56.520Z
          },
          _contents: Buffer(527) [Uint8Array] [
            105, 109, 112, 111, 114, 116,  32,  77,  97, 105, 110,  77,
            101, 115, 115,  97, 103, 101,  77, 101, 115, 115, 101, 110,
            103, 101, 114,  32, 102, 114, 111, 109,  32,  39,  46,  47,
            109, 101, 115, 115,  97, 103, 101,  47, 109,  97, 105, 110,
            109, 101, 115, 115,  97, 103, 101, 109,  97, 110,  97, 103,
            101, 114,  46, 106, 115,  39,  59,  32,  47,  47, 101, 115,
            108, 105, 110, 116,  45, 100, 105, 115,  97,  98, 108, 101,
             45, 108, 105, 110, 101,  13,  10, 105, 109, 112, 111, 114,
            116,  32,  77, 111,
            ... 427 more items
          ],
          history: [ 'C:\\WorkSpace\\gameshow\\src\\gameshow.js' ],
          _cwd: 'C:\\WorkSpace\\gameshow',
          _base: 'C:\\WorkSpace\\gameshow\\src',
          _isVinyl: true,
          _symlink: null
        },
        File {
          stat: Stats {
            dev: 1946988696,
            mode: 33206,
            nlink: 1,
            uid: 0,
            gid: 0,
            rdev: 0,
            blksize: 4096,
            ino: 1407374885448112,
            size: 3068,
            blocks: 8,
            atimeMs: 1686297160473.5981,
            mtimeMs: 1681546512408.303,
            ctimeMs: 1681546512408.303,
            birthtimeMs: 1678619944149.8179,
            atime: 2023-06-09T07:52:40.474Z,
            mtime: 2023-04-15T08:15:12.408Z,
            ctime: 2023-04-15T08:15:12.408Z,
            birthtime: 2023-03-12T11:19:04.150Z
          },
          _contents: Buffer(3068) [Uint8Array] [
            105, 109, 112, 111, 114, 116,  32,  77, 111, 100,  83,  99,
            114, 101, 101, 110,  77,  97, 110,  97, 103, 101, 114,  32,
            102, 114, 111, 109,  32,  39,  46,  47, 109, 111, 100,  47,
            109, 111, 100, 115,  99, 114, 101, 101, 110, 109,  97, 110,
             97, 103, 101, 114,  46, 106, 115,  39,  59,  13,  10,  13,
             10,  47,  42,  42,  13,  10,  32,  42,  32,  65,  32,  71,
             97, 109, 101,  32, 111, 102,  32,  79, 114, 100, 110, 117,
            110, 103, 115, 104, 117, 101, 116, 101, 114,  46,  13,  10,
             32,  42,  13,  10,
            ... 2968 more items
          ],
          history: [ 'C:\\WorkSpace\\gameshow\\src\\oh.js' ],
          _cwd: 'C:\\WorkSpace\\gameshow',
          _base: 'C:\\WorkSpace\\gameshow\\src',
          _isVinyl: true,
          _symlink: null
        },
        File {
          stat: Stats {
            dev: 1946988696,
            mode: 33206,
            nlink: 1,
            uid: 0,
            gid: 0,
            rdev: 0,
            blksize: 4096,
            ino: 360850920143085000,
            size: 2429,
            blocks: 8,
            atimeMs: 1686297160474.6038,
            mtimeMs: 1686076226349.0198,
            ctimeMs: 1686076226349.0198,
            birthtimeMs: 1686062037711.4128,
            atime: 2023-06-09T07:52:40.475Z,
            mtime: 2023-06-06T18:30:26.349Z,
            ctime: 2023-06-06T18:30:26.349Z,
            birthtime: 2023-06-06T14:33:57.711Z
          },
          _contents: Buffer(2429) [Uint8Array] [
             47,  42,  42,  13,  10,  32,  42,  32,  64, 102, 105, 108,
            101, 111, 118, 101, 114, 118, 105, 101, 119,  32,  84, 104,
            105, 115,  32, 102, 105, 108, 101,  32,  99, 111, 110, 116,
             97, 105, 110, 115,  32, 116, 104, 101,  32, 105, 109, 112,
            108, 101, 109, 101, 110, 116,  97, 116, 105, 111, 110,  32,
            111, 102,  32, 116, 104, 101,  32, 115, 105, 110, 103, 108,
            101, 116, 111, 110,  32,  99, 108,  97, 115, 115,  32, 123,
             64, 108, 105, 110, 107,  32,  68,  97, 116,  97,  82, 101,
            103, 105, 115, 116,
            ... 2329 more items
          ],
          history: [
            'C:\\WorkSpace\\gameshow\\src\\container\\dataregistry.js'
          ],
          _cwd: 'C:\\WorkSpace\\gameshow',
          _base: 'C:\\WorkSpace\\gameshow\\src',
          _isVinyl: true,
          _symlink: null
        },
        File {
          stat: Stats {
            dev: 1946988696,
            mode: 33206,
            nlink: 1,
            uid: 0,
            gid: 0,
            rdev: 0,
            blksize: 4096,
            ino: 2251799815609043,
            size: 1025,
            blocks: 8,
            atimeMs: 1686297160474.6038,
            mtimeMs: 1684851833757.3774,
            ctimeMs: 1686126485624.8916,
            birthtimeMs: 1684851173573.0974,
            atime: 2023-06-09T07:52:40.475Z,
            mtime: 2023-05-23T14:23:53.757Z,
            ctime: 2023-06-07T08:28:05.625Z,
            birthtime: 2023-05-23T14:12:53.573Z
          },
          _contents: Buffer(1025) [Uint8Array] [
             47,  42,  42,  13,  10,  32,  42,  32,  64, 102, 105, 108,
            101, 111, 118, 101, 114, 118, 105, 101, 119,  32,  84, 104,
            105, 115,  32, 102, 105, 108, 101,  32,  99, 111, 110, 116,
             97, 105, 110, 115,  32, 116, 104, 101,  32, 105, 109, 112,
            108, 101, 109, 101, 110, 116,  97, 116, 105, 111, 110,  32,
            111, 102,  32, 116, 104, 101,  32,  97,  98, 115, 116, 114,
             97,  99, 116,  32,  99, 108,  97, 115, 115,  32, 123,  64,
            108, 105, 110, 107,  32,  79,  98, 115, 101, 114, 118,  97,
             98, 108, 101,  73,
            ... 925 more items
          ],
          history: [
            'C:\\WorkSpace\\gameshow\\src\\container\\observableinfo.js'
          ],
          _cwd: 'C:\\WorkSpace\\gameshow',
          _base: 'C:\\WorkSpace\\gameshow\\src',
          _isVinyl: true,
          _symlink: null
        },
        File {
          stat: Stats {
            dev: 1946988696,
            mode: 33206,
            nlink: 1,
            uid: 0,
            gid: 0,
            rdev: 0,
            blksize: 4096,
            ino: 259801403503951070,
            size: 759,
            blocks: 8,
            atimeMs: 1686297160476.6,
            mtimeMs: 1683903315796.5876,
            ctimeMs: 1683903315796.5876,
            birthtimeMs: 1679318688314.783,
            atime: 2023-06-09T07:52:40.477Z,
            mtime: 2023-05-12T14:55:15.797Z,
            ctime: 2023-05-12T14:55:15.797Z,
            birthtime: 2023-03-20T13:24:48.315Z
          },
          _contents: Buffer(759) [Uint8Array] [
             47,  42,  42,  13,  10,  32,  42,  32,  64, 102, 105, 108,
            101, 111, 118, 101, 114, 118, 105, 101, 119,  32,  84, 104,
            105, 115,  32, 102, 105, 108, 101,  32,  99, 111
```

This is just the very beginning of the error dump. It's over `4000!!!` lines long. I believe that this comes from Nodejs, but I haven't found a way to suppress this message. I'm not asking about why my code crashes. Rather I don't want to have to open a new terminal each time i call the closure compiler or search for the few lines of useful information in the 4000 lines per call.

---

- Node.js v19.4.0
- google-closure-compiler@20230502.0.0
- gulp@4.0.2